# C# Searching through a excel workbook

Tags: c#, excel

i want to search an excel file using c# to find a specific sting of text (ASSEMBLY).I have this little code writed:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string File_name = "C:\\test.xls";
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook oWB;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet oSheet;
    try
    {
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(File_name, missing, missing, missing, missing,
            missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing,
            missing, missing, missing, missing);
        oSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)oWB.Worksheets[3];
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range oRng = GetSpecifiedRange("ASSEMBLY", oSheet);
        if (oRng != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Text found, position is Row:" + oRng.Row + " and column:" + oRng.Column);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Text is not found");
        }
        oWB.Close(false, missing, missing);

        oSheet = null;
        oWB = null;
        oXL.Quit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range GetSpecifiedRange(string matchStr, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet objWs)
{
    object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range currentFind = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range firstFind = null;
    currentFind = objWs.get_Range("A1", "AM100").Find(matchStr, missing,
                   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues,
                   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
                   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,
                   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, false, missing, missing);
    return currentFind;

}
```

This works ok, it can find the given string from the workbook. But, the workbook has many worksheets and now i'm only searching for one (sheet 3). How to search throught the whole workbook?

Also, this excel document has the word "ASSEMBLY" many times. How to keep searching and show all the results and not just the first one?

Comment: You are specifically asking for sheet 3 .. so that is what you are searching

Comment: To search each sheet, iterate them: `foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in oWB.Worksheets) {...}`.  To keep searching call `.FindNext`

Comment: for the post asker hope your post the answer you achieve for your question... thanks

Comment: @AlexK. please if you wish to make needed modification and post your comment as answer so i will mark it as answer... thank you in advance

Answer (score -1):

```
k = 1;
do { 
    oSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)oWB.Worksheets[k];
} while (k <= oWB.Worksheets.Count);
```